# Regexp for password validation

Tags: regex, forms

I'm creating a regexp for password validation to be used in a form.

- First letter should not be a special character. (Like this @abc12n.aa)
- First letter should be a alphabetic OR alphanumeric.
- And the remaining characters to be alphabetic or alphanumeric or any of the following special
  characters.(Like this Abc123@com or abc@123.sol)

I have tried this format

**regexp[^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9@#%&*]*$]**

but this is not working,can any one help on this

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9@#%&]` matches a single character from the given list. You need to add `+` after the character class to match one or more characters .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9@#%&.]*$
```

try this.This will work for you.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iY3eK8/4

Comment: It allowing the !^*_ special characters for above example.

Comment: @user it cannot be so

Comment: Please understand my problem clearly. 1.Special characters are does not allow password field at beginning character   
  ,and only allow the alphanumeric characters at beginning.
2.After that second character onwards allowed alphanumeric characters,special 
  characters.

Comment: but here i am entering ^^^abc and !!!123 and ***adc this examples are allowed.i want this special characters also not allowed.